# How to create element associated with an existing object

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I created the following two models...

```
const Account = sequelize.define("account",
{
    id_account: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {...},
    surname: {...},
    username: {...},
    password: {...}
},
{
    name: {
        singular: "Account",
        plural: "Accounts"
    },
    freezeTableName: true,
    hooks: {
        beforeSave: ((account, options) => {
            return bcrypt.hash(account.password, 10)
                .then(hash => {account.password = hash;})
                .catch(err => {throw new Error();});
        })
    }
});

const Genre = sequelize.define("genre",
{
    genre_name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(40),
        primaryKey: true
    },
    url_img: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(40),
        allowNull: false
    }
},
{
    name: {
        singular: "Genre",
        plural: "Genres"
    },
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

...and the following associations

```
Account.Genres = Account.belongsToMany(Genre, {
    through: "AccountGenre",
    foreignKey: "ref_account"
});
Genre.Accounts = Genere.belongsToMany(Account, {
    through: "AccountGenre",
    foreignKey: "ref_genre"
});
```

I created the following genres: Rock, Metal, Pop, Hardcore.
Now i want to create an Account and associate it 3 genres.
The following code creates the Account but doesn't create the association with the existing genres in the AccountGenre table:

```
const genresArray = ["Rock", "Metal", "Pop"];
const account = {...} // I have an object with account properties
Account.create({
    name: account.name,
    surname: account.cognome,
    username: account.nome_utente,
    password: account.password,
    genres: genresArray
}, {
    include: [Genre]
});
```

What's wrong in this code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you gave the reference to the 
association the plural name “Genres”. You need the same in the include statement.

include: [Genres]

Comment: I tried both Genres and Account.Genres but the ORM execute only the account creation query...